# is it possible to install IIS 7 on windows XP?

Tags: iis, iis-7

is it possible to install IIS 7 on windows XP ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, [IIS7 is not supported on Windows XP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Information_Services#Versions):

> - IIS 7.0, Windows Server 2008 and Windows Vista (Home Premium, Business,
>     Enterprise, Ultimate Editions)
> - IIS 7.5, Windows Server 2008 R2 and Windows 7